# How to get the YouTube app on AVD?

Tags: android, youtube

I made an app that plays a YouTube video but when I launch it on Android virtual device, it tells me that YouTube application is required for this app to work. How can I install the YouTube app on my AVD?
I don't have Google Play Services there.
I did try using adb install command but I got an error saying:
"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when installing an app (.apk file) that contains native libraries (.so files) for different architecture than device you are installing it on.

I can imagine you have yt APK for ARM architecture but trying to install it on an Intel-based emulator or device.  Side note: Genymotion is Intel-based device.

Go and check apkmirror, there are two kinds of yt .apk there:

http://www.apkmirror.com/?s=youtube&post_type=apps_post

see those X86s or ARM64s?

Make sure to get the right one for your emulator.